# cookie_file and cookie_jar, which one is for what?

Tags: curl

I am confused by the definitions of these.

Explain me in plain words which one is only for storing cookies and would not leak cookie to the server and which work both ways ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in curl lingo, the cookie file is the file to *read* cookies from and the cookie jar is the file that curl would *write* cookies to when the handle is closed.